# Splitting a single column in a .csv file into multiple columns with changes in headings and saving it in a new .csv file using Python 2

Tags: python, csv

I have a .csv file named **selected.csv** in **C:\Users\Win-8.1\Desktop\delhi** that contains 3 columns:

```
 Entries        |       Date (LT)    | AQI | Raw Conc.
 First Entry        01-01-2016 00:00   316     322
 Last Entry         31-12-2016 24:00   316     264
```

Now, what I want to do is:

i) Copy the data from this .csv file into a new empty .csv file named **corrected.csv** which I have created in the same folder.

The desired output should look like:

```
  Entries     |          Date    |    Month    |   Hour   | AQI | Raw Conc.
 First Entry              1         January       12 AM    316     322
 Last Entry              31        December       11 PM    316     264
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working code to the posted question is as follows:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

output_file = open(r"C:\Users\Win-8.1\Desktop\delhi\corrected.csv", "wb")
fieldnames = ['Date', 'Month' , 'Year', 'Hour', 'AQI' , 'Raw Conc.']
writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()

with open(r"C:\Users\Win-8.1\Desktop\delhi\selected.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        output_row = {}
        change_date = datetime.strptime(row['Date (LT)'], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
        output_row['Date'] = change_date.strftime('%d')
        output_row['Month'] = change_date.strftime('%B')
        output_row['Year'] = change_date.strftime('%Y')
        output_row['Hour'] = change_date.strftime('%I %p')
        output_row['AQI'] = row['AQI']
        output_row['Raw Conc.'] = row['Raw Conc.']
        writer.writerow(output_row)

output_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

output_file = open('C:\Users\Win-8.1\Desktop\delhi\corrected.csv', 'w')
fieldnames = ['Entries', 'Date', 'Month' , 'Hour', 'AQI' , 'Raw Conc']
writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()

with open('C:\Users\Win-8.1\Desktop\delhi\selected.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        output_row = {}
        output_row['Entries'] = row['Entries']
        change_date = datetime.strptime(row['Date (LT)'], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
        output_row['Date'] = change_date.strftime('%d')
        output_row['Month'] = change_date.strftime('%B')
        output_row['Hour'] = change_date.strftime('%I %p')
        output_row['AQI'] = row['AQI']
        output_row['Raw Conc'] = row['Raw Conc']
        writer.writerow(output_row)

output_file.close()
```

**Note :** I haven't tested the code so if you face any error let me know.

This is solution for your problem, but I would seriously suggest you to read more about [Python CSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and [Python Datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) library.This will help you for your future problem.

Comment: After `writer.writeheader(), I am getting the error: Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: change -> `open('C:\Users\Win-8.1\Desktop\delhi\corrected.csv')` to `open('C:\Users\Win-8.1\Desktop\delhi\corrected.csv', 'w')`

Comment: Only the headings got printed in the output. The data did not get copied. The error is: Traceback most recent call last:; File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>; Keyerror: 'Entries'.

Comment: Is it because my original file does not have the heading "Entries"?

Comment: open `selected.csv` file in `excel` and add `Entries` at first column, and then save as back as `selected.csv` and run code again

Comment: Even after adding `Entries` as the heading in the first column of **selected.csv**,  I am getting an error in line 6, which states that name 'temp' is not defined.

Comment: change `datetime.strptime(temp, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')` to `datetime.strptime(row['Date (LT)'], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')`

Comment: I forget to change that variable

Comment: Where? in line 14: change_date = datetime.strptime(row['Date (LT)'], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')

Comment: Perfect. Just one small question. How can I remove the single row spacing in the output?

Comment: @SujaiBanerji I didn't get what row spacing means.?

Comment: There is a single row of spacing between all the rows of data in the output.

Comment: Also, there is no column for the year of all the dates.

Comment: If a single row of spacing between all rows of data in the output is not required, then type 'wb' instead of 'w'.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to add the Hour column?

Comment: To answer my own question, type `output_row['Year'] = change_date.strftime('%Y')` in line 16.